# Using arrays to write variables into txt file in Python 3

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to calculate various numbers (mean, median, etc.) from a csv dataset and then write this information into a txt file. For reference, my dataset is SAT scores, so the sample I have below is code for SAT reading scores. Right now I am trying to use an array, and have this:

```
    a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
    b=[rmean, rmed, rmax, rmin, rsd, rvar]

    output=open("output.txt", "w")
    output.write("For the variable READ:\n The mean is")
    for i in range(len(a)):
        output.write(" %i %5.2f\n" % (a[i], b[i]))
    output.close()
```

I want my txt file to look something like:

> For the variable READ, the mean is [*value of rmean variable*], the
>   median is [*value of rmed variable*], etc.

How do I manipulate the array to do that, as opposed to the matrix view it's currently outputting? And additionally, is there any way to avoid having to use the numbers in array a or to avoid having them appear in my txt file output? Thank you!

Comment: Can you try to be more clear about exactly the issue? You say array, but you have two lists. You also mention a "matrix view", but what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Sorry about the terminology, very much a beginner here. I said matrix thinking mathematically to describe it, but the output is what you would expect, with two columns and 6 rows. Thomas helped me with a solution below, which might clarify the question if you were curious. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do I understand you correctly that you only want to print one line with all values and you have all values already calculated and saved as variables?
In that case there is no need for a for loop

```
output.write("For the variable READ:\n The mean is {0}, the median is {1}, the max is {2}, etc".format(rmean, rmedian, rmax, ...))
```

of if you want to read from your list

```
output.write("For the variable READ:\n The mean is {0}, the median is {1}, the max is {2}, etc".format(b[0], b[1], b[2], ...))
```

Comment: That's exactly it, thank you. So since the variables have already been defined, the array is completely unnecessary?

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be this one:

```
with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("For the variable READ:\n ")
    for i in range(len(a)):
        f.write("The %4s is %5.2f\n" %(b[i][1:], a[i]))
```

But if you modify your b as:

```
b = ['mean', 'median', 'max', 'min', 'sd', 'variance']


with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("For the variable READ:\n ")
    for i in range(len(a)):
        f.write("The %-8s is %5.2f\n" %(b[i], a[i]))
```